# How do I make a background image responsive?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using CSS and Bootstrap, I want to add a background image and place "Login" and "Register" buttons on that image.  My code so far:

```
   <!--   Header starts here!  -->      
   <header id="section_header" class="navbar-fixed-top main-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 

            <div class="navbar-header ">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div><!--Navbar header End-->

             <!--==== Begin of Navbar Collapse==-->


        </div><!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->       
</header> <!-- End header -->

 Here is my background image code and buttons[background image with login and register buttons][1]


<div style="background-image:url('images/loginbg.jpg');padding-bottom:    30%;background-size: cover;" class="wrapper">

        <div id="homebuttons" class="container">

            <!-- Login with a button -->
            <button style="top:170px; width:25%;"type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Login with SVAPP</button><br>

                <!--   Register with a button  -->       
                <br><br><a href="register.html"style="top:200px; width=25%" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical">       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Register with SVAPP </a>
   </div><!-- End buttons container-->
   </div> <!-- End Background image-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:
`background-size:cover`

or

`background-size:100%`

or

`background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: one another way: `background-size:100%` and `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: Hey thanks i got my image responsive.... But can you tell me, how to put buttons on that image,so that it should be responsive as well??

Comment: You should give width in `px` like `width:150px`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add `class="img-responsive"` in img tag which is predefined in the bootstrap.

Comment: what if we are using image in CSS?? Where to provide class??

Comment: in div where you are placing the image.